# Sistema de renovação de senha

Tags: php, mysql, conexão

Minha questão é que estou tentando fazer um sistema de redefinição de senha.

[ Senha atual ]
[ Nova senha ]
[ Trocar ]

Bom codigos abaixo

settings.php

```
<?php

 require_once('assets/system/core.php');

     if (isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $password = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = 'password'");

    if ($password->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $password->fetch_assoc()) {
                $userid = $row["id"];
            }
        }
    elseif(mysqli_num_rows($password) == 0)
    {
        echo '<div id="alert-error">Senha está incorreta!</div>';
        $passerror = true;
    }
}

     if (isset($_POST['npassword'])) {

    $npassword = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET password='".$_POST['npassword']."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['loginuser']."'");

    {
        echo '<div id="alert-green">Você foi registrado corretamente!</div>';
    }
}

    echo '
    <div class="wrapper-me">
        <div class="right-content" style="margin-left: 5px">
            <div id="box" style="min-height: 400px;  max-height: 1200px;">
                <div id="blue-title" style="background: #27ae60; border: 1px solid #27ae60">
                    <h1 id="title-config">Alterar minha senha</h1>
                    <i style="color:#e0e0e0;" class="ion-edit"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="content-config" style="height: auto;">
                    <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type
                      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha atual" class="button-contn1"/>
                       <input type="password" name="npassword" placeholder="Nova senha" class="button-contn1"/>
                      <input type="submit" value="Continuar" class="button-contn">
                    </form>
                    </div> '


    ?>
```

Não sei o erro, ele tá trocando a senha..
Mais ele não tá tipo meio que confirmando se realmente a senha atual consta no banco de dados.

Por favor, se alguem poder me ajudar agradeceria.

Comment: Só uma pergunta.. da onde saiu essa variavel `$l_query`?

Comment: Então amigo, eu acabei de editar essa variavel.. pra password.. foi um erro meu, mais ainda tá o erro.. ele troca a senha aparece duas mensagens " Você trocou sua senha corretamente e a do error junto " mais ele não ta verificando eu acho.

Comment: Primeiro você ta deixando a comparação fixa do password substituia por isso `$password = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '".$_POST['password']"."'");` e depois você seta um erro quando a senha não é encontrada `$passerror = true;` mas você não faz nenhuma condição com ela para dar a mensagem de erro e deixar de fazer o update.

Comment: Tudo certo amigo, já obrigado a força!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia , vejo alguns pontos bem errados no que você fez.
O pior é que desta maneira que foi programado se houver 2 senhas iguais vai dar problema.

Acredito que deva funcionar da seguinte maneira, vou postar aqui o código e você adapta caso necessário.

Presumimos que a pessoa esta logada e você gravou o id dela em uma sessão ou no caso vc obrigou ela a digitar o login em algum lugar também.

**form.php**

```
<div class="wrapper-me">
    <div class="right-content" style="margin-left: 5px">
        <div id="box" style="min-height: 400px;  max-height: 1200px;">
            <div id="blue-title" style="background: #27ae60; border: 1px solid #27ae60">
                <h1 id="title-config">Alterar minha senha</h1>
                <i style="color:#e0e0e0;" class="ion-edit"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="content-config" style="height: auto;">
                <form action="valida.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha atual" class="button-contn1"/>
                    <input type="password" name="npassword" placeholder="Nova senha" class="button-contn1"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continuar" class="button-contn">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**valida.php**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['npassword']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $sql= mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET password='".md5($_POST['npassword'])."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['loginuser']."' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($db)>0){
        echo "Senha alterada";
    } else {
        echo "Sua senha atual não coincide!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Ambos campos de senha devem estar preenchidos";
}
```

?>

qualquer dúvida é só avisar ^^

Comment: Amigo tudo certo já.. obrigado a força!

Comment: opa blz !! não esquece d marcar como concluido

Comment: Opa desculpa amigo, mais uma duvida aqui se der para me ajudar.. bom as senhas estão em md5 no banco.. então ta dando senha incorreta como faço para ler como md5?

Comment: vou fazer do meu cod para md5

Comment: Valeu amigo, funcionou ai no caso readaptei para uma pagina só no action"#" , e coloquei o codigo todo na mesma página resultado OK.
Tive que arrumar seu codigo que tá dando um erro.. mais fora isso já deu certo.

Comment: qual erro q deu ?

Comment: Deu erro de syntaxe acho que é assim que fala por causa que estava no mysql_query ($db,$sql;);  , ai arrumei seu codigo para oquê eu editei.

Comment: rss agora ta certo ^^

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, sua lógica tinha alguns problemas, mas tentei aproveitar o máximo do que você usou para evitar te confundir, o código ficou até mais feião mas a intenção é você entender, caso entenda você da uma melhorada.

**O código está seguindo esse ciclo abaixo:**

- Verifica se não está vazio os campos
- Criptografa as senhas que vieram via `POST` em `MD5`
- Pega o usuário do banco com os dados inseridos
- Verifica se a senha antiga não é igual a atual
- Atualiza o usuário com a nova senha e printa na tela o sucesso

**Segue abaixo o código comentado**

```
<?php

require_once('assets/system/core.php');

// Verifica se não está vazio os campos senha atual e nova senha
if (!empty($_POST['npassword']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    $pass = md5($_POST['password']);   // nova senha
    $npass = md5($_POST['npassword']);   // senha atual

    // Estou usando esse login user que você salvou na session.
    $npassword = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '$npass' and username = '".$_SESSION['loginuser']."'");

    // Verifica se ele achou algum usuario com o valor salvo na session loginuser e a senha digitada por ele
    if (mysqli_num_rows($npassword) > 0) {
        // verifica se a senha atual não é igual a antiga
        if ($pass != $npass ) {
            // caso o update ocorra corretamente ele printa o sucesso! (Recomendo usar um ID caso esse username não for uma chave primaria - PK)
            if ($password = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET password='".$_POST['npassword']."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['loginuser']."'")) {
                echo '<div id="alert-green">Senha alterada com sucesso!</div>';
            }
            else {
                  echo '<div id="alert-error">Algum prolema foi encontrado e sua senha não foi alterada!</div>';
            }
        }
        else {
             echo '<div id="alert-error">Senha atual é igual a senha antiga!</div>';
        }


    }
    else {
        echo '<div id="alert-error">Senha atual está incorreta!</div>';
        $passerror = true;
    }
}

// Printa o form quando ele não for enviado 

echo '
<div class="wrapper-me">
    <div class="right-content" style="margin-left: 5px">
        <div id="box" style="min-height: 400px;  max-height: 1200px;">
            <div id="blue-title" style="background: #27ae60; border: 1px solid #27ae60">
                <h1 id="title-config">Alterar minha senha</h1>
                <i style="color:#e0e0e0;" class="ion-edit"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="content-config" style="height: auto;">
                <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha atual" class="button-contn1"/>
                    <input type="password" name="npassword" placeholder="Nova senha" class="button-contn1"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continuar" class="button-contn">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> '
?>
```

Qualquer duvida, tamo ai!!

@Edit

Código alterado para transformar as senhas em md5.

Comment: Amigo já solucionado, mais tipo e se as senhas no banco for em MD5?

Comment: @LeoS Basta usar `md5($pass)` e comparar hash com hash! Se quiser eu altero a resposta usando md5, só pedir!

Comment: Por favor, se der para alterar agradeceria.. obrigado desde já amigo.

Comment: @LeoS Código alterado!!

Comment: Amigo, desculpa roubar mais tempo ai.. tipo ta dando mesmo error, achei que fosse o md5.. mais continua dando senha atual está incorreta.. oquê pode-ser? sera que é a chave primária? vou tentar com o id aquí.

Comment: @LeoS Verifica o que tem dentro do `$_SESSION['loginuser']` se você não estiver salvando nada na session ele não vai conseguir achar o usuário mesmo!! A query está correta!

Comment: Verifiquei aquí amigo, com o meu " .$_SESSION["userid"]. " onde é primary key que é o id.. nada tambem mesmo erro.. da que a senha está incorreta.

Comment: Resolvido aquí, adaptei o seu com o codigo de um amigo acima.. obrigado amigo.

Comment: @LeoS De nada mano!! Você já resolveu, mas eu achei o problema!! troquei para `mysqli_num_rows($npassword)` dentro do if! Caso eu tenha ajudado, deixa uma avaliação ai :D